# Is it possible to combine/layer images using UIImageView and still keep their transparency?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, calayer, alpha

I'm trying to combine some greyscale images with different alphas to create a layered affect. I'm loading images into a UIImageView and on screen it looks as expected. However, when I save the combined image, only the top layer gets saved; Is it possible to create and save a combined image layer?

I'm enclosing links to the images - one is a screenshot of what the images should look like (layered) and the other is the simple single-value one that ends up saving (non-layered).

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8263889/good.png - this is what I want
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8263889/bad.png - this is what happens.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to save to a UIImage? If so, try this.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
  [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

  UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return img;
}
```

Comment: that's almost exactly the code I had. I changed the few lines that were different but that didn't seem to make any difference...

Comment: @marina does your UIView contain all of the images you need(as subviews)?

Comment: it contains all the images as layers of a UIImageView. Here's the code that created the composite image on the screen:  (the parent UIView has a UIImageView (outlet imageView) that holds the images:

Comment: `UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`
        `UIImageView *newImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.imageView.frame];`

        `CGRect frame = self.imageView.frame;`
        
        `self.imageView.layer.opacity = .99;`

Comment: `if (self.imageView.image == nil)`
        `{`
            `self.imageView.image = image;`
            `self.imageView.layer.frame = frame;`
        `}`
           ` else`
        `{ // add a layered image`
            
            `newImgView.image = image;`
            `newImgView.layer.frame = frame;`
            
            `[self.imageView.layer addSublayer:newImgView.layer];`
        `}`

Comment: seems to be working now - i re-worked some other code and somehow it works! must have been a bug elsewhere. Thanks!